# Is Qlik Sense a new version of Qlikview or a new different product?

Tags: business-intelligence, qlikview, qliksense

I've heard both scenarios from different sources and there seem to be some impression on Qlik's product strategy for the future.

So, has someone understood if  `QlikSense` is a new version of `Qlikview` or a new different product?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Qlik Sense is a new product, addressing a whitespace in the BI/BA market. QlikView will continue to be developed for years.

Think of Qlik Sense as a SelfService Business Analytics/Data Discovery tool for the Enterprise. QlikView will however fit into being a Dashboard, Fixed Analysis and Reporting tool.

They are both building on the same core technology that made QlikView great. The next release of QlikView will feature stuff coming off the Next project (Next is codename for the Sense product).

Answer (score 0):

Qliksense is another product, the first of the new Qlik BI Suite called Qlik next